# Unitt: Establishing WebSocket Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, websocket

I'm using the Unitt library (http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient) to attempt to establish a connection to a local server via WebSockets within my iOS (iPhone) application.

I've successfully configured the project and am including the necessary project files, yet for some reason I cannot establish a simple connection.  The code I am using is:

in SomeWebsocket.m:

```
WebSocketConnectConfig* config = [WebSocketConnectConfig configWithURLString:@"ws://localhost" origin:nil protocols:nil tlsSettings:nil headers:nil verifySecurityKey:YES extensions:nil ];
config.closeTimeout = 15.0;
ws = [WebSocket webSocketWithConfig:config delegate:self];
[ws open];
```

in SomeViewController.m:

> ```
> MyWebSocket* myWS =[[MyWebSocket alloc] init];
> [myWS startMyWebSocket];
> ```

Unfortunately, when I run the script, the only output is, [via console/NSLog],:

> Oops. An error occurred.
>
> Oops. It closed.

The only thing I can think of is that, when attempting to perform the handshake/login, I'm not sending some additional information that I should be.  The server, for example, expects a username among other things.  Could this be the problem, or perhaps it's something unrelated?

I've been working on this for quite some time and I can' figure it out, so I would definitely appreciate any help.  Thanks.

EDIT:  With no changes, I'm now also getting errors like so:

> *** Assertion failure in -[AsyncSocket doCFReadStreamCallback:forStream:],
>   /Users/jmorris/Projects/xCode/UnitT/UnittWebSocketClient/trunk/UnittWebSocketClient/AsyncSocket.m:2811
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: theReadStream != NULL'

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what version of the web socket specification the server is running? I expect that your client version and your server version are experiencing a mismatch. It is only in the later versions of the specification that there is a clear way to communicate and handle such things. I am working on an update to the latest rev, but the holidays have made such things a bit challenging as of late. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket), a WebSocket library we just released. Supports [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (latest standard).  No CocoaAsyncSocket dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebSocketConnectConfig* config = [WebSocketConnectConfig 
                                  configWithURLString:kWebsocketURL 
                                  origin:nil
                                  protocols:nil 
                                  tlsSettings:nil 
                                  headers:nil 
                                  verifySecurityKey:YES 
                                  extensions:nil];

config.closeTimeout = -1;
config.timeout = -1;
   //   config.keepAlive = 5.0; //send ping from the server to keep socket alive 
WebSocket *ws1 = [WebSocket webSocketWithConfig:config delegate:shared];
```

This is the code that I am using and it works fine. I had problems with stoppingtimer so, i dont ping from the client but just from server side.